# Check if anything exist between two points

Tags: c#

Is there any way to check if there's anything between two points?

For example, there are two points A and C

If

```
A       B     C
```

, the method will return `true`, but if

```
A                 C
          B
```

, they are not on a same line so it will return `false`.

Comment: Please show what you already know... and what you have problem with.

Comment: More info please, not explained well enough I feel. Are the points elements in an array? Characters seperated by spaces in a string?...

Comment: What do you mean by points?

Comment: Your problem is a bit abstract :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest (maybe not the most efficient way) is to calculate the linear equation between A and C, and check if B satisfies it. If that is true, check if B is in the space between A and C, which is easier (compare B.x to A.x and C.x, and B.y to A.y and C.y).